# coversion from string ""to double type is invalid

Tags: vb.net

iam passing a textbox value(the value is 10:1:1) into a string and when iam running the application iam getting the following error "coversion from string "10:1:1" to double type is invalid". kindly find the code below and help me on the same: (also the textbox values should be greater than 0 always)

```
Dim strEncrypt As String = txtData.Text

If strEncrypt > 0 Then // I am getting the error here 
    txtEncryptedData.Text = Encrypt(strEncrypt)
Else 
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Enter the Value greater then 0:")
End If
```

Thanks,
Rams

Comment: if `txtData.Text = "10:1:1"`, how could you compare with 0? Which conversion are you using? How "10:1:1" can be compared with 0? It's normal your app complains...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want this...

If strEncrypt.Length > 0 Then

Comment: If so, even error message is wrong `"Enter the Value greater then 0:"`

Comment: Take a look at my answer: do you think this could be what OP wants?

Comment: Yeah, trying to guess intent without much information on this one.  There is probably a language barrier here too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want:

```
Function Check(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Dim parts As String()
    parts = s.Split(":")
    If parts.Length = 0 Then
        Check = False
    Else
        Check = True
        For Each sval As String In parts
            Check = Check And Int32.Parse(sval) > 0
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

so you can use it like `Check(txtData.Text)`.

Comment: HI macro thanks for your spontaneous answer it was really helpful the idea was correct but the string x:y:z should not have only 0 values it should have atleast 1. could you please help me on that

Comment: @user988904: my function returns false if string has zero values; otherwise returns true if first value is greater or equal than your min value...

Comment: hi macro, what i exactly need is in the string like x:y:z ,any of the x or y or z parts should not contain only zeros like (eg: 10:0:0 or 0:0:0)  the should contain value greater than zer like (10:5:2) etc..